# Catch data from JSON without a key

Tags: javascript, html, json

My problem is that i cant print what i recieve from a server with out having a key at the start of the JSON file, here is my current code...

```
    $.getJSON("http://10.21.26.251:8080/Transport/getMessage?user=1", function(data) {
    var output = "<tr>"; 
    for ( var i in data.item) {
    output += "<td>"
    + "-- "
    + data.item[i].messageId
    + " --<br>-- "
    + data.item[i].userId
    + " --<br>"
    + data.item[i].messageContent
    + "<br></br></td>";
    }
    output += "</tr>";
    document.getElementById("placeholder").innerHTML = output;
    });
```

But this is reliant on the code being recieved having a name of items, the current JSON is recieved like this... I have no control over what is recieved

```
    {
    "messageId": "d1e5afa5-5153-49b7-ae73-3501fbed1b68",
    "userTo": {
    "userId": 1,
    "userName": "COE",
    "userLastCheckedDate": 1362994638139
    },
    "userFrom": {
    "userId": 2,
    "userName": "Man",
    "userLastCheckedDate": 1362994638139
    }
    etc...
```

Comment: I don't see any `item` key, so is that the issue?

Comment: JSON.stringify what you get ? console.log ? What are you trying to do ?

Comment: thats the point, item isnt there! I need to reference it without a key

Answer (score 0):

Its difficult to get an idea of the json schema with such a small sample, but assuming it is a list of emails i would try this:

```
$.getJSON("http://10.21.26.251:8080/Transport/getMessage?user=1", function(data) {
var output = "<tr>"; 
for ( var i = 0; i < data.length;i++) {
output += "<td>"
+ "-- "
+ data[i].messageId
+ " --<br>-- "
+ data[i].userFrom.userId
+ " --<br>"
+ data[i].messageContent
+ "<br></br></td>";
}
output += "</tr>";
document.getElementById("placeholder").innerHTML = output;
});
```

Comment: Hi, thanks that hasnt worked there still isnt anything output by the script

Comment: It might not be an array, try taking out the for loop and just use data.messageId

Comment: Even without the for loop it wont even find one of the data fields inside the json file

Answer (score 0):

If I understood what you're trying to do, you basically want to loop through the JSON object properties without knowing their names. Also (correct me if I'm wrong), your object seems to be an array of objects.
You could do something like this:

```
var output = "<tr>";

for (var i=0; i<data.length; i++) { // Loop through the main array of objects

    output += "<td>";

    $.each(data[i], function(key, val) { // Loop through the properties of the current object
        output += "-- "
            + val
            + " --<br>";
    });

    output += "</br></td>";
}
output += "</tr>";
document.getElementById("placeholder").innerHTML = output;
```

Comment: His thanks, that hasnt worked there still is nothing output by the script

Comment: A question: is your JSON between square brackets (something like `[{"messageId":"something", ...}, {...}, {...}]`) or is just a series of `{}, {}, ...` as you posted before?

Comment: It is between [] yes sorry i ma have missed that part when coping it over

Comment: Ok. I just updated my answer, I forgot the closing parenthesis for the `$.each()` function. Could you try it?

Comment: Hmm, no that wasnt it i added that in when i tried it! It seems to read exactly the same file when it is saved and work but has trouble when getting it from the server

Comment: Well, then I guess we need to know what comes from the server. Can you post a full example? Your previous snippet is not clear enough.